# CakePHP: ошибка в организации связи между таблицами

Tags: cakephp

Доброго времени суток. Помогите найти ошибку.
Есть таблицы товара и категорий:

```
goods {id, cat_id, name, cost, count}
category {id, name}
```

Одному товару - одна категория.
Судя по [мануалу](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html), должно выйти так:

```
// Model/Goods.php
class Category extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Category';
}

class Goods extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo  = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className'    => 'Category',
            'foreignKey'   => 'cat_id'
        )
    ); 
}

// Controller/GoodsController.php
class GoodsController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        debug($this->Good->find('all'));
    }
...
```

Но выводится только содержание 1й таблицы. Что я делаю не так, где ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс модели у вас зовется Good**s** а дергаете вы его пытаетесь как Good

Comment: Если убрать "s", то ошибка вызова функции "find" будет. И все же, данные из таблицы "goods" берутся.

Comment: Этого я не понимаю, так быть не должно, согласно документации http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: вот что выходит, если добавить "s":
"Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object"
Я сам только начал копать пирог - представляете как я удивился? у меня просто разрыв шаблона...

Comment: Я так понял, что по имени используемой таблицы должен называться класс. Добавлял такое, но не помогло:

     public $hasMany = array(
             'Goods' => array(
                 'className' => 'Goods',
             )
         );

Comment: Очень странно, а сделайте дамп $this->Good, на какую вообще модель он указывает

Comment: ООП в php - это что то страшное.

Comment: в общем, переименовал во всех скриптах "Goods" на "Good". Получил "Error: Table categories for model Category was not found in datasource default." Переименовал таблицу категорий во множественное число - все заработало... Но это же жесть - одна буковка решает столько всего.

Comment: @IamS Здравствуйте, как там в 90-х?

Comment: @Antiless Именно для таких случаев существует правило - сущность в БД должна именоваться в единственном числе